# Kubernetes error: unable to launch the editor "jed"

Tags: kubernetes, edit, configmap

I am trying to edit configmap in kubernetes but I am getting for below error.

$kubectl edit configmap

error: unable to launch the editor "jed"

can anyone know how to resolve this or any other method to edit configmap.

Answer (score 2):

kubectl edit will open the editor defined by your KUBE_EDITOR, or EDITOR environment variables, or fall back to ‘vi’ for Linux or ‘notepad’ for Windows. So you can set a different editor in KUBE_EDITOR or EDITOR and see if that works.

Comment: Yes. i am able to open configmap after setting EDITOR="vi"